# how change sticky select option link to add to cart link in woocommerce on sticky select option button for variable product

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I m new at Woocommerce. I want to change the sticky select option link in add to cart link in woocommerce on the sticky select option button for variable products. The product should be directly added to the cart. I want to do this when clicked add to cart at the bottom sticky it should add the default selected size into the cart. I don't have knowledge of PHP. I tried some below code but it only changed the select option to add to the cart text and the product is not added to the cart. [image]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_variable_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_variable_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text ) {
   global $product;
   if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $add_to_cart_text = __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
   }
   return $add_to_cart_text;
}
```

[image]

I want to do when clicked add to cart at the bottom sticky it should add the default selected size into cart.

the links is below..
https://neobery.com/product/lavender-essential-oil-100-percent-pure-organic-natural-for-hair-skin-body/

Comment: This will require knowlage in js to make it work. The simpliest way i can think off is to just simulate clicking on sticky button to actualy click on the real button. That way you will keep it simple $('.sticky-button').on('click', function(){ $('.real-button').click(); }); change your classes to target the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try below code snippet

**Add below code inside function.php**

```
function my_custom_script()
{
?>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).on(
      "click",
      ".single_link_to_cart_button",
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('form.cart :submit').click();
      }
    );
  </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_custom_script');
```

Comment: @MohammadSuhail Check updated answer you can't modify it from `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_variable_add_to_cart_text' );
` 

So I prefer to use `wp_footer` action

Comment: Can I rename the select option into add to cart only on the product page? and the page should not move upward.

Comment: if I make  add to cart  near the product sticky on the bottom, it will be fine and I will remove the sticky option from the theme

Comment: Is that any plugin that created the sticky banner. If yes then try once default settings with it. If no setting found then you could try various options for rename or string change with JS or WordPress `gettext` action also.

Comment: And scroll to top is may be the same way you need to look or you can trick it by adding extended JS code. Or create another specific question after you got stuck again in code

Comment: If you got your resolution for current question you can proceed with the accepting my answer.